# Navigate from Android application settings to corresponding app settings

Tags: android, notifications, application-settings

In whatsapp application, when we go to:
settings --> application manager --> whatsapp --> app info --> notifications
There is an option called show settings or a settings button(Nougat only).
On clicking that, the whatsapp settings page will be loaded.

Any idea how to do that? or is there any docs available for customizing the settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES" />`

adding an intent filter with the above category will add settings option in your app info > notifications page.

Answer (score 0):

I  recommend to open the App settings screen

```
 public static void startInstalledAppDetailsActivity(final Activity context) {
if (context == null) {
    return;
}
final Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
context.startActivity(i);
```

}

or try this

```
public static Intent newAppDetailsIntent(Context context, String packageName) {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
    return intent;
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings",
            "com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails");
    intent.putExtra("pkg", packageName);
    return intent;
}
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings",
        "com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails");
intent.putExtra("com.android.settings.ApplicationPkgName", packageName);
return intent;
}
```

Comment: I want to navigate from the android settings of my application to the settings inside my application. Not the reverse

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below code in your Manifest file for that **particular activity** which you want to be displayed after clicking on App Settings in Device Settings :

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS" />              
</intent-filter>
```